# Match radial lens distortion of two videos taken with two different actioncams with different FOV

Tags: math, ffmpeg, distortion

I have two different actioncams with different `k1` and `k2`. How do I calculate `k1` and `k2` for one video not to be "defished", but have the same amount of distortion as the other video?